# Jquery slidedown if statement not comparing $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of buttons to be clicked on.  I want a div to slide down if the link that is clicked is new, but if it is the same one that was last clicked, I just want the div to slide up.

So my code is:

```
var $lastflyout = '';
$('.links-text a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if($(this) == $lastflyout) {
            alert('last equals');
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
            $('#flyout').slideDown(500);
        }
        $lastflyout = $(this);


    });

});
```

And for some reason it is never alerting 'last equals', thus never getting into the first if statement.  I tried alerting $lastflyout and it says that it is an object after the first click but I don't know why that first if statement isn't working.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried comparing the element itself rather than the jQuery element?

```
var lastflyout = '';
$('.links-text a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if(this == lastflyout) {
            alert('last equals');
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
            $('#flyout').slideDown(500);
        }
        lastflyout = this;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why use a global variable when it's not necessary?

Comment: @Gísli Konráð - I know you edited the OP's method, but it's not the best method of solving the problem - that was my point and I was hoping the OP could learn/understand that.  Using a global variable when it's not needed is rarely or ever the optimal solution.  SO shouldn't just be about the first answer that works - it should be about the best answer and the OP should benefit from that too.  I don't care which one gets the checkmark, I just want to call the OP's attention to the non-global variable solution that's also a lot less code.

Comment: @jfriend How do you know that the variable is global? That whole block of code could easily be in a closure for all we know, right?

Comment: @PaulPro - wherever it is, it isn't needed.  I've made my point so the OP could see a shorter, better way to do it - that's all I was trying to point out.

Answer (score 4):

Two equivalent objects are not equal unless they are the exact same object. Since $() makes a clone of an object:

```
$(this) == $(this)
```

is always false. If you just use the ordinary JS object instead of jQuery and make an alias to it instead of a clone it will work:

```
if(this == lastflyout) {
    alert('last equals');
    $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
}
else {
    $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
    $('#flyout').slideDown(500);
}
lastflyout = this;
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparing two jQuery objects is not a good idea at all.  They are probably different jQuery objects even though they have the same HTML elements inside of them.

If you want to stay with this approach, save `this`, not `$(this)` in the global variable and compare to `this`.

I would recommend that you get rid of the global variable all together and just check the state of the flyout by either looking at it's visibility.  After sliding up, jQuery makes the item not visible, so you can just check whether it's visible or not.

You can see an example with no global variable here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/sgXe8/.

```
$(this).click(function() {
    var flyout = $("#flyout");
    if (flyout.is(":visible")) {
        flyout.slideUp(500);
    } else {
        flyout.slideDown(500);
    }
});
```

Even better, `.slideToggle()` will do the comparison for you:

```
$(this).click(function() {
    $("#flyout").slideToggle(500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toggleSlide instead! take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/4LTSp/

**HTML:**

```
<span class="links-text"><a href="#">Toggle Slide Link</a></span>

  <p id="flyout">
    This is the paragraph to end all paragraphs.  You
    should feel <em>lucky</em> to have seen such a paragraph in
    your life.  Congratulations!
  </p>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".links-text a").click(function () {
  $("#flyout").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to reference the most recent link clicked, I would either assign the $lastflyout equal to the id of the anchor or the href of the anchor.

Try rather something like this:

```
var $lastflyout = '';
$('.links-text a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('id') == $lastflyout) {
            alert('last equals');
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
            $('#flyout').slideDown(500);
        }
        $lastflyout = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

If you don't have an id for each anchor, you could also use this:

```
var $lastflyout = '';
$('.links-text a').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href') == $lastflyout) {
            alert('last equals');
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
        }
        else {
            $('#flyout').slideUp(500);
            $('#flyout').slideDown(500);
        }
        $lastflyout = $(this).attr('href');
    });
});
```